# Set Gridview Height as Percentage ASP.Net

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview control on a page. My page all heights are in percentages. Since all divs are working fine. Only gridview does not accepting percentage because I put fixed header on gridview control to show its header.

If I give pixles to its class, it accept and put scrollbar aside. But if I give percentage like 10% or 20% gridview fill with all records and expand till end.

My code is as follows:

css Class **

```
.containergrid {
    height: 10%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: forestgreen;
}
```

gridview control **

```
<div class="containergrid">
    <asp:GridView ID="grdCost" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" ShowHeader="false"
        DataKeyNames="CostID"
        OnRowCommand="grdCost_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdCost_RowDataBound"
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" CellPadding="1" GridLines="None" Font-Size="Small">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CostName">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Percentage" DataFormatString="{0:0}%">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Active">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Option">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" CommandName="editRecord"
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CostID") + "," + Eval("CostName") + "," + Eval("Percentage") + "," + Eval("Active")%>' runat="server">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="padding-left:30px"></span>
                    </asp:LinkButton>

                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="deleteRecord"
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CostID") + "," + Eval("CostName")%>' runat="server">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-md-pull-1"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are using Bootstrap's CSS within a GridView - you have to look at the rendered page and see what the GridView is overriding. Also, GridView's render an outer div which may be messing with the CSS hierarchy

Comment: Yes I am using bootstrap to make it responsive. Its not working even I put my gridview in another page which as only gridview control.